# Camera Services Failed in android

Tags: android, android-camera

`Capimage` `Activity`:

```
public class Capimage extends Activity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback
{
    //a variable to store a reference to the Image View at the main.xml file
    private ImageView iv_image;
    //a variable to store a reference to the Surface View at the main.xml            file
    private SurfaceView sv;
    //a bitmap to display the captured image
    private Bitmap bmp;
    //Camera variables
    //a surface holder
    private SurfaceHolder sHolder;
    //a variable to control the camera
     Camera mCamera;
    //the camera parameters
    private Parameters parameters;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.captures);

        //get the Image View at the main.xml file
        iv_image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);

        //get the Surface View at the main.xml file
        sv = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surfaceView);

        //Get a surface
        sHolder = sv.getHolder();

        //add the callback interface methods defined below as the Surface View callbacks
        sHolder.addCallback(this);

        //tells Android that this surface will have its data constantly replaced
        sHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3)
    {
        //get camera parameters
        parameters = mCamera.getParameters();

        //set camera parameters
        mCamera.setParameters(parameters);
        mCamera.startPreview();

        //sets what code should be executed after the picture is taken
        Camera.PictureCallback mCall = new Camera.PictureCallback()
        {
            @Override
            public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera)
            {
                //decode the data obtained by the camera into a Bitmap
                bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);
                //set the iv_image
                iv_image.setImageBitmap(bmp);
            }
        };

        mCamera.takePicture(null, null, mCall);
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder)
    {
        // The Surface has been created, acquire the camera and tell it where
        // to draw the preview.

        try {
            mCamera = Camera.open();
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);

        } catch (IOException exception) {
            mCamera.release();
            mCamera = null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder)
    {
        //stop the preview
        mCamera.stopPreview();
        //release the camera
        mCamera.release();
        //unbind the camera from this object
        mCamera = null;
    }
}
```

**Logcat**

```
E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example22.dell.goodprj, PID: 9965
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Fail to connect to camera service
            at android.hardware.Camera.native_setup(Native Method)
            at android.hardware.Camera.<init>(Camera.java:469)
            at android.hardware.Camera.open(Camera.java:442)
            at com.example22.dell.goodprj.Capimage.surfaceCreated(Unknown Source)
            at android.view.SurfaceView.updateWindow(SurfaceView.java:671)
            at android.view.SurfaceView.access$000(SurfaceView.java:90)
            at android.view.SurfaceView$3.onPreDraw(SurfaceView.java:195)
            at android.view.ViewTreeObserver.dispatchOnPreDraw(ViewTreeObserver.java:847)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2197)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1192)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6231)
            at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:788)
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus"/>
    <uses-permission    android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.hardware.camera.FLASH"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your camera was not ready. Make you to catch this:

```
try {
    mCamera = Camera.open();
    mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
}
catch (Exception exception) {
    if (mCamera != null) {
        mCamera.release();
    }
    mCamera = null;
}
```

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.example22.dell.magicgoodapp.MainActivity.surfaceCreated(Unknown Source)
now showing this error in logcat

Comment: i have checked the updated answer but its still showing NullPointerException

Comment: Post the stacktrace, I cannot guess where that `NullPointerException` rises from...

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.example22.dell.magicgoodapp.MainActivity.surfaceChanged(Unknown Source) this is what logcat is showing

Comment: Update your original post to show the entire logcat